# How to open directly storage settings of an application from settings

Tags: android, settings

I developed an Android Package Manager (I know there are a lot on the play store...). With intent "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTING" and its parameter "package:xxx" I am able to display android settings for that application.

But I would like to be able to open directly storage setting of it without displaying first screen in order to clear cache more easily without too much interaction.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any specific intent going to that "sub screen" in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Hey, I'm pretty sure that this is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. All my unsuccessful researches lead me to agree with you... My other option is to use accessibility service. I did it to "force stop" application but I didn't succeed in scrolling down and clicking on storage item of first screen...